# Firebase - Prevent child_added when delete with limitToLast

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i want to build mini webchat - When view site i set show 5 messages and if view more, you can click button. All things are fine but when i remove 1 node, firebase auto add last node into, how can i prevent it?
Ex: I have node A,B,C,D,E,F,G. I had loaded list C,D,E,F,G but when i delete 1 in all, it auto add B into list.

```
    <div id="messgesDiv">
    <center><h3>Message</h3></center>
  </div>
  <div style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <input type="text" id="nameInput" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="text" id="messageInput" placeholder="Message" data-id="">
    <input type="text" id="idproject" placeholder="ID Project">
  </div>
  <button id="delete">Delete Test</button>
  <button id="edit">Edit</button>
  <button id="loadmore">Load more</button>
  <button id="showlastkey">Show last key</button>
```

My javascript

```
$('#loadmore').click(function() {
    i = 0; old = first;
    myDataRef.orderByKey().endAt(first).limitToLast(6).on('child_added', function (snapshot){
      if( i == 0)
        first = snapshot.key();
      var message = snapshot.val();
      if(snapshot.key() != old)
        displayChatMessage(message.name, message.text, message.idproject, 'old');
      i++;
      console.log('myDataRef.orderByKey().endAt(first).limitToLast(6)');
    });
  });

  $("#messageInput").keypress(function (e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){ //Enter
      var name = $("#nameInput").val();
      var text = $("#messageInput").val();
      var idproject = $("#idproject").val();
      if($("#messageInput").data("id")=='')
      {
        myDataRef.push({name: name, text: text, idproject: idproject});
      }
      else
      {
        myDataRef.child(key).update({name: name, text: text, idproject: idproject});
        $('#messageInput').attr('data-id', '');
      }
      $("#messageInput").val("");
    }
  });


    myDataRef.limitToLast(5).on('child_added', function (snapshot){
      if( i == 0)
        first = snapshot.key();
      var message = snapshot.val();
      displayChatMessage(snapshot.key(), message.name, message.text, message.idproject, 'new');
      i++;
      console.log(snapshot.key());
      console.log(' myDataRef.limitToLast(5)');
    });



  function displayChatMessage(key, name, text, idproject, status){
    //console.log(name + " -- " + text + " -- " +idproject);
    if( status == 'new')
    {
      $('<div/>', { 'data-id': key , 'class' : 'test'}).text(text + " - ").prepend($('<em/>').text(name+": " )).append("IdProject: "+idproject).appendTo($("#messgesDiv"));
      $("#messgesDiv")[0].scrollTop = $("#messgesDiv")[0].scrollHeight;
    }
    else
    {
      $('<div/>', { 'data-id': key , 'class' : 'test'}).text(text + " - ").prepend($('<em/>').text(name+": " )).append("IdProject: "+idproject).insertAfter($("center"));
      $("#messgesDiv")[0].scrollTop = $("#messgesDiv")[0].scrollHeight;
    }
  }

  $('#delete').click(function() {
    myDataRef.child(key).remove();
    $('#messgesDiv').filter('[data-id="'+key+'"]').remove();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase limit queries act like a *view* on top of the data. So if you create a query for the 5 most recent messages, the Firebase client will ensure that you always have the 5 most recent messages.

Say you start with these messages:

```
message1
message2
message3
message4
message5
```

Now if you add a message6, you will get:

```
child_removed message1
child_added message6
```

So that your total local view becomes:

```
message2
message3
message4
message5
message6
```

Conversely when you remove message 6 again, you get these events:

```
child_removed message6
child_added message1 (before message2)
```

So that you can update the UI and end up with the correct list again.

There is no way to change this behavior of the API. So if you want to handle the situation differently, you will have to do this in your client-side code.

Your code currently only handles `child_added`. If you have add a handler for `child_removed` you'll see that you can easily keep the user interface in sync with the data.

Alternatively you can detect that the message is already in your UI by comparing the key of the message you're adding to the ones already present in the DOM:

```
function displayChatMessage(key, name, text, idproject, status){
  var exists = $("div[data-id='" + key + "']").length;
  if (status == 'new' && !exists) {
    $('<div/>', { 'data-id': key , 'class' : 'test'}).text(text + " - ").prepend($('<em/>').text(name+": " )).append("IdProject: "+idproject).appendTo($("#messgesDiv"));
    $("#messgesDiv")[0].scrollTop = $("#messgesDiv")[0].scrollHeight;
  }
  else {
    $('<div/>', { 'data-id': key , 'class' : 'test'}).text(text + " - ").prepend($('<em/>').text(name+": " )).append("IdProject: "+idproject).insertAfter($("center"));
    $("#messgesDiv")[0].scrollTop = $("#messgesDiv")[0].scrollHeight;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a better way to fix this? I understand that the handler always try to keep the same number of messages, but this only works if you always want to keep  that number of messages in screen. In almost all cases, you already loaded older messages and just keep adding more.